# Visualize CSV and MAT file as graph in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, csv, eclipse-plugin, mat, graph-visualization

I am looking for a solution, to visualize data from a `*.csv` and `*.mat` file in form of a plot, which should work as an eclipse plugin, as I am developing an Eclipse product.

During research I found [ICE Embedded Visualizations](https://wiki.eclipse.org/ICE_Embedded_Visualizations) but this seems to be a standalone product without a possibility to add it as a plugin inside my Eclispe product.

I don'n need 3D CAD, but just the vizualization of `*.csv` and preferably also `*.mat`.

Can someone give an advice?

Answer (score 1):

Seems that there is not yet an Eclipse Update Site or [Eclipse Marketplace](https://github.com/eclipse/ice) entry yet for [ICE](https://wiki.eclipse.org/ICE).

A way to just get the ICE plug-ins would be to clone their git repository from [GitHub - ICE](https://github.com/eclipse/ice) and follow the [ICE Build Instructions](http://wiki.eclipse.org/ICE_Build_Instructions) on how to do this.

This should make the ICE plug-ins available in your local Eclipse (RCP) development environment and also ready for extending them, for your own Eclipse plug-in(s).

In case you only need to quickly edit `.csv` files, you can search for [csv on the Eclipse Marketplace](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/search/site/csv), and find an csv editor.